# strtotime is not correctly working for -60 days

Tags: php, strtotime

I am trying to compare two dates, but looks to me for some reason using -60 days is not working for strtotime.

```
$date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-60 days")); // gives me string) 2016-09-25 09:27:26
$today_dt = strtotime($date);
$expire_dt = strtotime($result['insertedInvoice']); // insertedInvoice shows 2016-11-24 08:56:48

if( $today_dt > $expire_dt){
 dothis();
}else{
  dothat();
}
```

The problem is that in this function it should go for the `dothis();` but instead its going for `dothat();`  Since $today_dt is like 60 days behind, it cant be greater than $expire_dt.

Comment: 60 days ago was a smaller time than the invoice date. Looks OK to me.

Comment: your code looks ok. what is the issue?

Comment: As per your code is $today_dt = 2016-09-25 15:12:00. and $expire_dt = ' 2016-11-24 08:56:48'.  Then dothat(); will show. Check your condition. As per your comment the condition should be if( $today_dt < $expire_dt){

Comment: @apokryfos it should be pointing to dothis() , but goes to do that..

Comment: @Farhana `if today_dt is bigger than expire date then do this` but today **IS NOT** bigger than expire date so it goes to `dothat()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try following**,

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$date =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-60 days', strtotime($now)));
$today_dt = strtotime($date);
$expire_dt = strtotime($result['insertedInvoice']); // insertedInvoice shows 2016-11-24 08:56:48

if( $today_dt > $expire_dt){
 dothis();
}else{
  dothat();
}
```

** I write this code as per your code, please check **if** condition. If needed change **if** condition as follows 
(I am little bit confused with your last sentence)

```
if( $today_dt < $expire_dt){
   dothis();
} else {
   dothat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use DateTime instead:

```
$date = new DateTime( '-60 days' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Today
echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($today . ' - 60 days'));

Hope this will helps you.
```